# Radio button list populate without selected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, linq-to-entities

I have below code. The radio button list populate without selected value. I expect to see one of the options selected when the list is initially loaded Please see the photo. Anybody can help me out will be great appreciate.

[image]

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductEditViewModel : Product
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorieItems { get; set; }
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(Int32 ProductId)
{
    var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

    var q = from p in northwind.Products
            where p.ProductID == ProductId
            select new ProductEditViewModel
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                SupplierItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers select new SelectListItem { Text = sup.CompanyName, Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sup.SupplierID), Selected = sup.SupplierID == p.SupplierID },
                CategorieItems = from cat in northwind.Categories select new SelectListItem { Text = cat.CategoryName, Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cat.CategoryID), Selected = cat.CategoryID == p.CategoryID },
                Discontinued = p.Discontinued
            };

    return View(q.SingleOrDefault());
}


@foreach (var Categorie in Model.CategorieItems)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.CategoryID, Categorie.Value) @Categorie.Text; @:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question as it is not clear. Are you expecting to see one of the options selected when the list is initially loaded?

Comment: Yes. I expect to see one of the options selected when the list is initially loaded

Comment: So how do you know which item is selected from your categories list. Is this contained in your model view? if so put a conditional check in to set that as the selected item

Comment: not sure what the structure is but with a form you usually have a $_POST['value'] to check. You could check for this value and if it is absent, set a default value to use.

Comment: `CategorieItems` is a SelectList! (which is for use in `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here. First you do not appear to have a property your binding to, and second, you are using a `SelectList` which is for use in `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. In your view model

```
public class ProductEditViewModel : Product
{
  public int SelectedCategory { get; set; } // if this is not already a property of class Product
  public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; } // not a SelectList
  ....
}
```

In you action method, populate the categories (`from cat in northwind.Categories`?). Then in the view

```
@foreach (var Categorie in Model.Categories)
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Categorie.CategoryID) <span>@Category.CategoryName</span>
}
```

Now, if the value of `SelectedCategory` matches the `CategoryID` of one of the Category items, it will be selected and if you select another item, it will correctly post back.